# asp.net mvc no longer getting values from subclass

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Disclaimer; I'm a mvc nub.
I'm kinda stuck, this worked like a couple of days ago, and I'm not sure why it doesn't now. The problem is I'm not getting the subclass data back, only the data from the "normal" properties. I'm populating 5 rows from within Global.asax, and the table ReDayModels is in the DB. The keys are okay also in the DB.

edit: Both tables ReWeekModel and ReDayModel has data. I'm using code first approach.

I have this DB:

```
public class ReChronoDB : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ReWeekRowModel> WeekRows { get; set; }        
}
```

And this is my DbSet rows

```
public class ReWeekRowModel
{
    public ReWeekRowModel()
    {
        CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        Days = new List<ReDayModel>()
        {
            new ReDayModel {DayName = DayOfWeek.Monday},
            new ReDayModel {DayName = DayOfWeek.Tuesday},
            new ReDayModel {DayName = DayOfWeek.Wednesday},
            new ReDayModel {DayName = DayOfWeek.Thursday},
            new ReDayModel {DayName = DayOfWeek.Friday},
            new ReDayModel {DayName = DayOfWeek.Saturday},
            new ReDayModel {DayName = DayOfWeek.Sunday}
        };
    }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; private set; }
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    [DisplayName("Week #"), Range(1, 53)]
    public int WeekOfYear { get; set; } 
    [Range(2017,2075)]
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public List<ReDayModel> Days { get; set; } 
    public Priority Priority { get; set; }
    public Status Status { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; } 
    public Responsible Responsible { get; set; }
    public ResponseGroup ResponseGroup { get; set; }
    public string CaseRef { get; set; } 
    [StringLength(75), DisplayName("Short Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; } 
    public string Details { get; set; } 

}
```

And here the subclass:

```
public class ReDayModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DayOfWeek DayName { get; set; }
    public double Hours { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
}
```

And finally, here is the controller with the Index Action.

```
public class ReChronoController : Controller
{
    ReChronoDB _reChronoDb = new ReChronoDB();

    // GET: ReChrono
    public ActionResult Index(string responsegroup = "", string responsible = "", int week = 0, int year = 0)
    {
        CultureInfo ciCurr = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        ViewBag.CurrentWeek = ciCurr.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(DateTime.Now, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek,
            DayOfWeek.Monday);
        ViewBag.CurrentYear = ciCurr.Calendar.GetYear(DateTime.Today);


        var model = _reChronoDb.WeekRows.ToList();

        // For dropdownlists
        ViewBag.Years = _reChronoDb.WeekRows.Select(r => r.Year).Distinct();
        ViewBag.Weeks = _reChronoDb.WeekRows.Select(r => r.WeekOfYear).Distinct();

        var filteredmodel = ReChronoDomainLayer.FilteredWeekRows(model, responsegroup, responsible, week, year);

        return View(filteredmodel);
    }
}
```

When I hover over the "model" variable and drill down, the Days collection for the rows have no values.

edit: Here is the sql that is being executed:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[CreatedDate] AS [CreatedDate], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[WeekOfYear] AS [WeekOfYear], 
[Extent1].[Year] AS [Year], 
[Extent1].[Priority] AS [Priority], 
[Extent1].[Status] AS [Status], 
[Extent1].[Category] AS [Category], 
[Extent1].[Responsible] AS [Responsible], 
[Extent1].[ResponseGroup] AS [ResponseGroup], 
[Extent1].[CaseRef] AS [CaseRef], 
[Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
[Extent1].[Details] AS [Details]
FROM [dbo].[ReWeekRowModels] AS [Extent1]
```

edit: this is the context?

```
public class ReChronoDBInitializer : 
    DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ReChronoDB>
{
    protected override void Seed(ReChronoDB context)
    {
        base.Seed(context);

        var enumToLookup = new EnumToLookup();

        enumToLookup.Apply(context);

        ReChronoDomainLayer.CreateDummyEntries(context);
    }
}
```

Seems like its completely ignoring the List Days collection.

I've also tried without the filteredmodel, but i left it in here, so you understand why I have parameters in the action.

Any ideas?

Comment: What approach EF are you using? Add also DdContext. You have data in ReDayModel table?

Comment: @M.Wiśnicki code first. what do you mean by add dbcontext?.. Both tables ReWeekModel and ReDayModel has data.

Comment: It looks like here you have a `1-*` (1-to-many) relationship between `ReWeekRowModel` and `ReDayModel`. What are your foreign keys in the table? Check out this link. http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx. I suspect it is because you do not have the `virtual` keyword on `public List<ReDayModel> Days { get; set; }`

Comment: Are you disabling lazy loading or dynamic proxies as well? Looking at the SQL generated, it is clear it is not joining on the `ReDayModel` table.

Comment: @coolboyjules The relation is many-many ? A week contains many days (7), a day can exist in many weeks (52-53). Thanks for your input :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all please make sure that `ReDayModel` is part of `ReChronoDB` as well:

```
public class ReChronoDB : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ReWeekRowModel> WeekRows { get; set; }    
    public DbSet<ReDayModel> DayRows { get; set; }    
}
```

Now your controller action attempts to use lazy loading but it is disabled due to incorrect property type for `Days` property. If you want to enabled lazy loading your class should look like this:

```
public class ReWeekRowModel
{
   ...
   public virtual ICollection<ReDayModel> Days { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

As an alternative you can use eager loading which would require a change in your action to use `.Include()` method:

```
public class ReChronoController : Controller
{
    ...
    public ActionResult Index(string responsegroup = "", string responsible = "", int week = 0, int year = 0)
    {
       ...
       var model = _reChronoDb.WeekRows.Include(w => w.Days).ToList();
       ...
    }
}
```

If you always need the `Days` collection this might result in better performance. Please read more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx).

Comment: This is working now. I did not need to put ReDayModel in the DbSet. I did not need to use Include either. The thing that help seems to be making the Days collection virtual. Side note, when I made the Days collection virtual, it created duplicated ReDayModels because of the constructur (dunno why).. Resharper gave me a warning. I'm marking it as solved because your answer led me to the solution. Thanks!